# Natural orientation with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, transform-orientation

I'm trying to orientate the two half spheres with the line. I did a lot of test but no ones gives the result I hope.

[image]

My Geometry Nodes

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you are:

[image]

this is, what the align euler to vector nodes does!

Comment: Thanks Chris ! If I show you all things I tested I'm sure you laugh :D

Comment: if i would show you all things i tried with GN (and failed) you would laugh more... :D